# How to replace text between two asterisks with something else?

Tags: php, html, string

I am allowing the user to enter text into a textarea, but where `*https://example.com/image.png*` (a URL surrounded by asterisk) is written it needs to take the URL (it should always be a URL) and then it will insert it into an `<img />` tag and then replace the URL and the asterisk with the image tag.

I am able to catch the event once but I am unsure on how to find this multiple times. In an example it will replace the original:

```
*https://example.com/image.png*
```

with:

```
<img src="https://example.com/image.png" />
```

**EDIT:**

As a simple example:

Input:

```
A load of random text *http://example.com/image.png* some more text. Some more text *http://example.com/image2.jpg* the end.
```

It needs to be able to find each of the two asterisk and get what is inside.

For Example:

```
http://example.com/image.png
http://example.com/image2.jpg
```

So that I can then use the URL's to display images.

And then finish with something like this:

```
A load of random text <img src="http://example.com/image.png" /> some more text. Some more text <img src="http://example.com/image2.jpg" /> the end.
```

Comment: and the question is about?

Comment: @donald123 The best way to go about doing this

Comment: What is 'this' exactly?! It's pretty unclear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @DannyFranklin Make a simple example: input; current output; expected output

Comment: @Rizier123 I have updated my original question, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: @DannyFranklin Now your question is much clearer. Now it's the question where are you stuck to get this done? Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done using regex:

```
$string = 'A load of random text *http://example.com/image.png* some more text. Some more text *http://example.com/image2.jpg* the end.';
$pattern = '/\*(.*?)\*/';
$replacement = '<img src="$1" />';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Regarding the pattern, `\*` matches a literal `*`, and `(.*?)` captures anything (but consisting of as few characters as possible) between the two stars.

See the regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/rJ8lX7/1). Read the PHP documentation on `preg_replace` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

If this accepts user input, you should probably think about [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) issues.